# How to use a multiple kubernetes resource file through kubernetes python client similar to kubectl apply -f

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-python-client, ambassador

I have a kubernetes multi-resource file which contains different resources that are to be applied for e.g. deployment-definition, service-defintion, pv, pvc etc. Is there any way to use this single file through kubernetes python client to deploy all these resources **at once** ?
Though my scenario is a bit different. I have a file which use CRDs alongwith custom kubernetes resource objects for e.g. **Deployment + ambassador's Mapping**. How to achieve this using **kubernetes python client**?

Answer (score 0):

With the client, you have to do them all separately. When you have multiple documents in a YAML file, kubectl just splits them for you and makes an API call for each.

Comment: But how to do this for CRDs ?

Comment: Do you mean making API calls against custom objects? https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md shows how to do that, also the examples are autogenerated and terrible.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a kubernetes multi-resource file
>    Is there any way to use this single file through kubernetes python client to deploy all these resources **at once** ?

Please check the content of [`examples`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6709b753b4ad2e09aa472b6452bbad9f96e264e3/examples/create_deployment.py) directory.

```py
    from os import path

    import yaml

    from kubernetes import client, config


    def main():
        # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper
        # utility. If no argument provided, the config will be loaded from
        # default location.
        config.load_kube_config()

        with open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "nginx-deployment.yaml")) as f:
            dep = yaml.safe_load(f)
            k8s_beta = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api()
            resp = k8s_beta.create_namespaced_deployment(
                body=dep, namespace="default")
            print("Deployment created. status='%s'" % str(resp.status))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Important note:  it's a must to use triple dashes at the top of your yaml file and in-between resources, if it contains more than one resource.

[.../utils/create_from_yaml.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/utils/create_from_yaml.py#L24) and [.../examples/create_deployment_from_yaml.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6709b753b4ad2e09aa472b6452bbad9f96e264e3/examples/create_deployment_from_yaml.py) are worth checking as well.

> I have a file which use CRDs alongwith custom kubernetes resource objects

as @coderanger told, the example can be found in [.../docs/CustomObjectsApi.md](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use config.new_client_from_config to [manage multi clusters](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/multiple_clusters.py).

or use kube config from dict not local file.

```
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client import Configuration, ApiClient

def new_client_from_dict(conf: dict, context: str):
    """
    create client via conf dict
    """
    client_config = type.__call__(Configuration)
    config.load_kube_config_from_dict(config_dict=conf, context=context, persist_config=False,
                                  client_configuration=client_config)
    return ApiClient(configuration=client_config)

client1 = client.CoreV1Api(api_client=new_client_from_dict(CLUSTER1_KUBE_CONFIG, context='cluster1'))
client2 = client.CoreV1Api(api_client=new_client_from_dict(CLUSTER2_KUBE_CONFIG, context='cluster2'))
client1.list_namespaced_pod()
client2.list_namespaced_pod()
```